# Error on ALTER TYPE in postgres relation does not exist

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Using the following:

```
CREATE TYPE user_types AS ENUM ('it', 'accounting', 'processes');

CREATE TABLE my_users
(
    my_user_id integer NOT NULL,
    my_user_name text NOT NULL,
    my_user_type user_types
)
```

I want to change one of the user types:

```
ALTER TYPE user_types RENAME ATTRIBUTE it TO softwaredev CASCADE;
```

I get a error:

```
ERROR: relation "user_types" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01
```

I tried adding quotes and backticks but that didn't help. The example I wrote down here is not the exact code, my type has 31 characters, but I don't think the length of my type is the issue.

I'm using postgres version 9.6.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ALTER TYPE ... RENAME ATTRIBUTE` only works for composite types, not for `ENUM` types.

While there is a way to add new entries to such a type (`ALTER TYPE ... ADD VALUE 'new_value'`), there is no supported way to remove or rename an enumeration entry.

If you are not afraid to mess with the catalogs, you can try as superuser:

```
UPDATE pg_enum
SET enumlabel = 'softwaredev'
WHERE enumtypid = 'user_types'::regtype
  AND enumlabel = 'it';
```

From PostgreSQL v10 on, you can use

```
ALTER TYPE ... RENAME VALUE ... TO ...
```

Comment: Ah... too bad. So it is either messing with the catalogs or creating a new type and removing the old. Thanks for your answer!!

Comment: @DeniseMeander With the upcoming Postgres 10 you can rename enum values: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-altertype.html

Comment: Thanks. I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can rename the ENUM to a different name and then recreate your desired ENUM again with the updated fields and change reference of the table column to the new ENUM.

Here is a Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9b9ed/3

Credit to this from https://www.munderwood.ca/index.php/2015/05/28/altering-postgresql-columns-from-one-enum-to-another/