# Alter Type in PgSQL to rename attribute not working

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to rename an attribute of a Type in PgSQL using following Alter command

```
ALTER TYPE typeName
  RENAME ATTRIBUTE attrNameOld TO attrNameNew
CASCADE
```

PgSQL version is 9.5, running on Ubuntu 16.04

However, I receive following error on my Pgsql CLI

```
ERROR:  relation "<typeName>" does not exist
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Then apparently your type is not named `typename` but something different. Note that `typename` is a different name than `"typeName"`

Comment: is it an enum type? then you might want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44243336/error-on-alter-type-in-postgres-relation-does-not-exist

Comment: maybe this help https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18484/tuning-postgresql-for-large-amounts-of-ram

Comment: As Horse said, in postgresql unless you add double quotes the fieldname are consider lower case. So you may need use `"typeName"`

Comment: thanks @StephanSchlecht for the link. So, I can't do what I am trying to. PgSQL version 9.x does not allow Attribute rename

Answer (score 0):

So, I can't rename an `Attribute` in PostgreSQL version <10. Thanks to Stephen for sharing the [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44243945/1278203).

Alternatives are available though

1. Remove the Type. Create anew with right Values, and update Table references
2. Update Catalogs